# Different theme for each language in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, themes

I would like to know: there is a way to have a different theme for each language in Eclipse IDE? For example: the default white theme for Java editor and a dark theme for PHP.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Usually people have multiple eclipse-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different workspaces, lets say you have workspace with dark theme called "X" when you connect to a new one eclipse will load the default theme, so what you need to do is have one workspace per language and set a theme for each one and switch between them with File > Switch workspace.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well this actually helps indeed! And what about if I have a project with 2 different languages?

Comment: @GiancarloSalton Well... then you'll most likely have the theme color of the workspace you have opened. I know that you can do exactly what you are asking in netbeans without needing to change the workspace under tools > options > fonts & colors > Syntax there you just chose the language and add a "profile" to it. So, since netbeans allows you to import eclipse projects, why don't you just switch to netbeans? If that is an important feature for yourself just try it out, its pretty much the same as eclipse, I used to work with it before moving to eclipse without any drama involved.